# Execute code scala from spark in Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I would like to run a scala code on Zeppelin from Spark cluster.

For example: 
This is code into hdfs Spark "HelloWorldScala.scala":

```
object HelloWorldScala{
 def main (arg: Array[String]): Unit = {
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp_Enrico")

 val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
 val aList = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
 val aRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(aList)
 println("********* HELLO WORLD AND HELLO SPARK!! ******")
 println("Print even numbers")
 aRdd.filter(x=>x%2==0).map(x=>x*2).collect().foreach(println)
  }

}
```

I would like to import in Zeppelin the HelloWorldScala file and run main, but I see the error:

Error code Zeppelin

[image: Error code Zeppelin screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't import single file in Zeppelin. You can pack your scala files into `.jar` library and put it to `spark.jars` (setted as property in spark) directory, after you will can import your library using line: `import your.libray.packages.YourClass` and using non-private functions from it. If you don't know about `jar` packages, and `spark.jar` directories just read a bit more about that.

UPDATE:

```
%dep
z.load("your_package_group:artifact:version")
%spark

import com.yourpackage.HelloWorldScala
```

Comment: I created a jar file "AppSparkTest.jar". The structure of the jar file is: -src -main -scala -com -test -HelloWorldScala.scala.

Next I set the property %spark in Zeppelin by inserting the path jars in `spark.jars`. Finally I do the import in this way `import com.test.HelloWorldScala` but I see the error `<console>: 23: error: object test is not a member of package com`. Why?

Comment: do you have `package com.test` line in top of HelloWorldScala.scala ? how you created jar? did you use sbt package for that?

Comment: I created the jar with intelliJ IDEA, then "build artifact". I have also `package com.test` in top of HelloWorldScala.scala

Comment: maybe you need to do so: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/APACHE-ZEPPELIN-ON-HDP-2-4-2/ta-p/246221